# How to get sum of SWITCH measure within the same week and compare?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I currently have a measure that splits a project's total work hours evenly across the lifespan of the project on a daily basis. And dates outside of the project's start and end dates will be 0 hours.

**Table:**

| Project ID | Total Work Hours | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 01 January 2023 | 09 January 2023 |
| 2 | 50 | 05 January 2023 | 30 January 2023 |
| 3 | 200 | 10 January 2023 | 29 January 2023 |
| 4 | 75 | 16 January 2023 | 03 February 2023 |
| 5 | 125 | 02 February 2023 | 21 February 2023 |

**Measure:**

```
Daily_Hours = 
VAR current_day = CALCULATE(MAX(CALENDAR_TABLE[Date]))
VAR start_date = CALCULATE(MAX(Project_Table[Start Date]))
VAR end_date = CALCULATE(MAX(Project_Table[End Date]))
VAR date_diff = CALCULATE(DATEDIFF(start_date, end_date, DAY))
VAR daily = DIVIDE(CALCULATE(MAX(Project_Table[Total Work Hours])), date_diff)
RETURN
SWITCH(TRUE(),
    (current_day >= start_date && current_day <= end_date) = False, 0,
    daily
)
```

**Measure for visual (to get correct row totals):**

```
Daily_Hours_Visual = 
VAR __table = SUMMARIZE(Project_Table, Project_Table[Project ID], "_VALUE", [Daily_Hours])
RETURN
IF(HASONEVALUE(Project_Table[Project ID]), [Daily_Hours], SUMX(__table, [_VALUE]))
```

Which produces this matrix when (`Project ID` in Rows, a `Calendar_Table` hierarchy in Columns and the measure `Daily_Hours_Visual` in Values)

[image]

How would I go about summing up the hours that are within the same year-week number and then compare it to a value? For example, for the first week of 2023, I would like to see

```
12.50 + 12.50 + 12.50 + 12.50 + 14.50 + 14.50 + 14.50 = 93.50
```

And then compare it to say the value 100. Since 93.50 is less than 100, it's within budget etc.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, would it not just be something like this: `CALCULATE(SUM(Project_Table[Total Work Hours]), REMOVEFILTERS(CALENDAR_TABLE[Date]))`?

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz This would sum the total work hours column across each of the projects, but would not take into account the project's start and end dates (and the hours distributed across this timeframe). I may need to set something up in addition to your suggestion, but as of now it shows a total of 550 for each day or each week etc. (even past the project's end date).

Comment: Ah, so `Project_Table` does not have a relationship to `Calendar_Table` and this needs to be calculated based on the dates in the Project table?